# Achieving vertical structure from horizontally placed divs

Tags: html, css

I have a list of div elements that act as buttons. They have hover functionality from its CSS. I am placing them all in horizontal line. But I want them to be placed vertically that is one after another in the same line. I am not sure how I can do it since the width attribute places it in the same line.

How do I place them as new line function with certain equal distance?

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        }


        h1 {
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-top: 125px;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            line-height: 23px;
        }

        /* --- Start progress bar --- */

        .process-wrapper {
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 1080px;
        }

        #progress-bar-container  {
            position: relative;
            width: 90%;
            margin: auto;
            height: 100px;
            margin-top: 65px;
        }

        #progress-bar-container ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding-top: 15px;
            z-index: 9999;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: -40px
        }

        #progress-bar-container li:before {
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: solid 2px #aaa;
            transition: all ease 0.3s;

        }

        #progress-bar-container li.active:before,
        #progress-bar-container li:hover:before {
            border: solid 2px #fff;

            background: linear-gradient(to right, #1a00aa 0%, rgb(0, 81, 255) 100%);
        }

        #progress-bar-container li {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #aaa;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 11px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: 700;
            transition: all ease 0.2s;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            height: 60px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #progress-bar-container li .step-inner {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #progress-bar-container li.active,
        #progress-bar-container li:hover {
            color: #444;
        }

        #progress-bar-container li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            width: 6px;
            height: 6px;
            background: #777;
            margin: auto;
            border: solid 7px #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-top: 40px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 13px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            transition: all ease 0.2s;

        }

        #progress-bar-container li:hover:after {
            background: #555;
        }

        #progress-bar-container li.active:after {
            background: #207893;
        }
```

```html
<div class="process-wrapper">
        <div id="progress-bar-container">
            <ul>
                <li class="step step01 active">
                    <div class="step-inner">A</div> 
                </li>
                <li class="step step02">
                    <div class="step-inner">B</div>
                </li>
                <li class="step step03">
                    <div class="step-inner">C</div>
                </li>
                <li class="step step04">
                    <div class="step-inner">D</div>
                </li>
                <li class="step step05">
                    <div class="step-inner">E</div>
                </li>
            </ul>

    </div>      
    </div>
```

Comment: Your terms confuse me. What is "vertically in the same line"? Lines are normally horizontal.

Comment: Also, if they _act_ as buttons, shouldn't they _be_ buttons?

Comment: @isherwood i meant they should be placed vertically in the same line.- as they are now placed horizontally in the same line/height. Yes they should be buttons but for this question I actually removed js which triggers the functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure what JS has to do with element type. So you want your divs arranged in a column? Divs are block by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add flex and flex-direction as column to the ul tag.

```
#progress-bar-container ul{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding-top: 15px;
   z-index: 9999;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: -40px
}
```

For more information just look at this link
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You should copy the snippet from the question post and update it to demonstrate.